# Construction of a join function of infinitely many derivatives.

Tags: analysis

I am curious if anyone can construct a function made up of more than one e.g. $|x| = x, x\geq 0$ and $-x, x\leq 0$. However I would require that it must be infinitely differentiable and in the above case of $|x|$ it must be infinitely differentiable at 0. I suspect that we can't find one but if anyone has an example or a rigorous explanation as to why it doesn't work it would be grateful.

Comment: What do you mean "made up of more than one"? Are you looking at piecewise defined functions? In such a case, you need each piece to be differentiable, and that side derivatives coincide at the gluing points. In your case, $x$ and $-x$ do not fill the bill.

Comment: ofcourse, sorry I forgot the term for a brief second. Yes you do need something at the gluing points, but I want an example where they glue infinitely many times

Comment: at the peaks of what specifically? are you saying at the joining points do some form of a convolution or what?

Comment: (I meant the peaks of $\sin (x)^n$, n being an exponent)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard example is $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}e^{-1/x},& x>0\\ 0,& x\le 0\end{array}\right.$$
$f$ is infinitely differentiable everywhere.

Comment: thankyou, that helps greatly